# Testing dart ajax HttpRequest

Tags: ajax, dart, dart-async

I'm not quite sure I understand what's going on when I try testing post HttpRequest. Here's the code of my class that does the job:

```
import 'dart:html';

class HttpReportAdapter {

  var    logmaster;
  int    log_level = 2;
  String url;

  HttpReportAdapter(this.url) {}

  post(r, level) {

    var data = {
      'message'   : r,
      'log_level' : log_level.toString(),
    };

    if(this.logmaster != null)
     data['log_level_string'] = this.logmaster.log_level_as_string(level);

    return HttpRequest.postFormData(this.url, data);

  }

}
```

An here's the test code:

```
import '../lib/report_adapters/http_report_adapter.dart';
import "package:test/test.dart";

void main() {

  var adapter;

  setUp(() {
    adapter = new HttpReportAdapter("http://localhost:4567/errors");
  });

  test("sends an ajax request and acknowledges a 200 response from the server", () {
    adapter.post("message", 2).then((_) => print("!!!!!!!!!"));
  });

}
```

For now, as you can see, I'm not even trying to test anything, just output something. While running this, the request does indeed to to `http://localhost:4567/errors` and I can see it in my server's logs.

However, the `!!!!!!!!` isn't printed.
Additionally, the test fails with:

```
This test failed after it had already completed. Make sure to use 
[expectAsync] or the [completes] matcher when testing async code.
```

However, if I force my server to sleep for 1 second before sending a response, the test passes without an error.

I would appreciate if someone would help me make some sense of it all, and, consequently, write the correct test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `Future` so the test can wait for it to complete

```
return adapter.post("message", 2).then((_) => print("!!!!!!!!!"));
```

Otherwise the test completes before the response from the server arrives.

Comment: But `HttpRequest.postFormData` already returns a Future and that's what I'm returning from my `post()` method. https://api.dartlang.org/1.14.2/dart-html/HttpRequest/postFormData.html

Comment: Oh, I see, return from the test itself, got it. I just tried that and here's the error I'm getting an error with a strange output: `[object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent]`

Comment: Please try to print `event.target.status` and `event.target.statusText` where `event` is the `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to do it. I have no idea what outputs `[object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent]`, I don't have any print statements in my code. And I can't get that object from anywhere because all I got is a Future.

Comment: Can you try with this URL instead? https://cors-test.appspot.com/test. I tried your code locally and it's working fine for me. I assume you're running into a CORS issue.

Comment: I thought so. However, if I was running into a CORS issue, then the requests shouldn't be passing through, yet I see my backend server's logs and it receives the request. Additionally, the domain name (localhost) is the same as in the Dartium browser that opens up tests.To simplify, I created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954761/error-when-trying-to-test-an-async-dart-ajax-httprequest/36955058?noredirect=1#comment61471072_36955058 Hope it helps. I will try your URL too and will report back.

Comment: A GET request is not sent at all as long as you don't have any authorization headers. For a POST request in CORS situations there is **always** an OPTIONS request being sent before the actual POST request is sent. If the response to the OPTIONS request doesn't provide the correct headers the actual POST request isn't sent. Not only the domain name, also the port needs to be the same. If you test with the URL I posted above you know immediately if it's a CORS issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've checked the URL you provided - it works, the test passes. Does that mean I need to return correct headers from my own backend for the test to pass with localhost:4567?

Comment: Yup, I think that should fix it.