# Error when trying to test an async Dart ajax HttpRequest

Tags: ajax, dart, async-await, dart-async

This question is a simplified version of this one: [Testing dart ajax HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945795/testing-dart-ajax-httprequest/36945844)

I basically removed all the unnecessary code leaving only the test and `HttpRequest.postFormData` call.

**The problem**: test doesn't seem to wait until the Future completes.
The test code:

```
# http_report_adapter_test.dart

import "package:test/test.dart";
import 'dart:html';

void main() {

  test("sends an ajax request and acknowledges a 200 response from the server", () {
    var f = HttpRequest.postFormData("http://localhost:4567/errors", { 'hello': 'world'});
    f.then((_) => print("!!!!!!!"));
    return f;
  });

}
```

As per advice, I `return f` and the test is supposed to wait until the Future completes. However, this is the output I'm getting instead:

```
~/Work/my_libs/dart/logmaster master$ dtest-d -n "sends an ajax request and acknowledges a 200 response from the server"
00:05 +0 -1: test/http_report_adapter_test.dart: sends an ajax request and acknowledges a 200 response from the server
  [object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent]
  dart:html                            HttpRequest.postFormData
  http_report_adapter_test.dart 14:25  main.<fn>

  [object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent]
  dart:html                            HttpRequest.postFormData
  http_report_adapter_test.dart 14:25  main.<fn>
```

I think I clearly am misunderstanding something fundamental. I've tried multiple variations of this test, with `async/await`, `expectAsync`, `completion`, but nothing seems to be working. Would appreciate any good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
  test("sends an ajax request and acknowledges a 200 response from the server", () async {
    await HttpRequest.postFormData("http://localhost:4567/errors", { 'hello': 'world'});

    print("hello!"); // or expect(x, y);
  });
```

Comment: I've made the exact changes you suggested and here's the output: http://pastie.org/10818961

Comment: Looks like your test is failing. And unfortunately, the Http errors don't help much.

Comment: Yeah, but why would it fail? I mean, there's just one line which uses Dart's std lib class - `HttpRequest` . The server it's trying to connect to clearly receives the request (I can see it in the logs). There is literally 0 of my own code here.